# Using GNUPLOT with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv, gnuplot

I have linked my OpenCV + Qt with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I would like to link it now with GNULOT.

Do you think it's possible to do so to draw some charts by extracting some informations from the different IplImages?

Frankly, I think it's soo complicated to deal with that [link](http://www.shervinemami.info/graphs.html) when it's about to draw some graphs.

Answer (score 3):

If you want add some charts (with lots of functionality), think, it's good idea to use this well-documented lib: Qwt (http://qwt.sourceforge.net/). Also, there is [qwt](/questions/tagged/qwt)-tag on StackOverflow, related to this library.

Also, more simpler is to use plotting widget `QCustomPlot` from http://www.workslikeclockwork.com/index.php/components/qt-plotting-widget/

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I have used Qwt (http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) in my project and it's a simple and easy way to plot the graphs. I suggest you use it for your project too. It integrates well with Qt too.

Comment: I've not used QCustomPlot before, but this seems to throw some light on the comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067411/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-qcustomplot-compared-to-qwt